# Post multidimensional array in Mysql

Tags: php, sql, multidimensional-array, pdo, prepared-statement

I want to post a multidimensional array into Mysql.

The code I have to know.

```
if (isset($_POST['husers[]'])) {
    $query = $db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET highlighted_users = ( ? ) WHERE user_id = '" . $userId . "'");
    $query->bindParam(1, $_POST['husers[]']);
    $query->execute();
}
```

The data I have:

```
array (size=4)
  'text' => string 'bla' (length=3)
  'another text' => &string '' (length=0)
  'husers' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string '100486' (length=6)
      1 => string '13474' (length=5)
      2 => string '179339' (length=6)
      3 => string '184729' (length=6)
      4 => string '150593' (length=6)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) will do the trick for you.

```
if (isset($_POST['husers'])) {
    $query = $db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET highlighted_users = ( ? ) WHERE user_id = '" . $userId . "'");
    $query->bindParam(1, serialize($_POST['husers']));
    $query->execute();
}
```

When you are pulling it out of the database you'll need to use the function [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to get it to a normal array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_encode` function of php. By this you can stora data as string. When retrieving it from database,  by `json_decode`function yu can make it array again.

```
if (isset($_POST['husers'])) {
    $query = $db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET highlighted_users = ( ? ) WHERE 
    user_id = '" . $userId . "'");
    $query->bindParam(1, json_eoncode($_POST['husers']));
    $query->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the data as a simple comma-separate string:

```
if(isset($_POST['husers'])){  // changed $_POST key reference
    $husers_csv=implode(',',$_POST['husers']);
    $stmt=$db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET highlighted_users=? WHERE user_id=?");  // removed (), added another placeholder
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$husers_csv);
    $stmt->bindParam(2,$user_id);
    $status=$stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) this data, then store it as a json string. When you pull the data back out simple [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)() to get your array back.

```
if (isset($_POST['husers'])) {
    $query = $db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET highlighted_users = ( ? ) WHERE user_id = '" . $userId . "'");
    $query->bindParam(1, json_encode($_POST['husers']));
    $query->execute();
}
```